# Use a field's generated value as another field's default value in prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have this `User` model in prisma (postgres), I want to use the same value `cuid()` generates for `id` in `username`. How do I achieve that?

```
model User {
  id               String    @id @default(cuid())
  username         String?   @unique

}
```

I know I can just regenerate `cuid()` for a different value, it would still work for what I am working on,  but I want user's id and username to be same by default.

Comment: This is a very poor design. Why are you storing the exact same data point twice in the same table. If you need to refer to it with two names just alias in the select or create a view.

Comment: Can you explain your use case on what you are trying to achieve, As Belayer mentioned you should not duplicate your data, and in the schema file you can assign a default value but it cannot be dependent on other field.

Comment: @Belayer Basically this is my first time trying to build a full stack twitter clone type thing, I make users sign up using OAuth, so the username remains empty by default, I want the user to have the same username as their ID. its not really necessary I just thought it might be easier to manage since both will be same for each indiviual user. and I didnt knew it was a bad design choice, Can you explain me on that a little? I am really new to this thing. I want the user to be able to change username if they want to but give a default username same as their ID.